# Find and reject outliers of circles in individual video frames - OpenCV

Tags: opencv

[Circles with outlier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNPAM.png)

Link to picture I am working with is above. I am working with OpenCV and C#. i have a video running at 30FPS and I am trying to find the circles using the Hough algorithm (varying levels of light in the video mean I have to adapt the parameters on the fly). The picture shows the problem I am having. Depending on how the camera moves, the algorithm may mark a circle where there is none.

What I would like to do is find and disregard these false circles as outliers using the point list the program generates of each circle's center point location  (list is below). Basically, I would rather the circle not be displayed if it has a low likelihood of being correct. I was thinking of writing a function that uses the population standard deviation of each circle's location (circles are relatively uniform distance apart in video) and disregarding circles that are more than two or three standard deviations off in that frame.

My biggest limitation is that this calculation needs to be run for each frame so I need to make it as efficient as possible (several things going on in the background which are also consuming CPU cycles). I found a function on Stack Overflow to calculate Standard Deviation which looks like it may work, but it's only for a single value. I need to figure out how to apply it to coordinates or just think of another way to solve the problem. Here is the code and the point list:

```
public static double StandardDeviation(this IEnumerable<double> values)
{
    double avg = values.Average();
    return Math.Sqrt(values.Average(v=>Math.Pow(v-avg,2)));
}
```

List pointList = new List() {new PointF(122.5F, 157.5F),
new PointF(77.5F, 232.5F),
new PointF(167.5F, 237.5F),
new PointF(42.5F, 152.5F),
new PointF(172.5F, 82.5F),
new PointF(212.5F, 162.5F),
new PointF(257.5F, 242.5F),
new PointF(122.5F, 307.5F),
new PointF(87.5F, 82.5F),
new PointF(32.5F, 302.5F),
new PointF(207.5F, 317.5F),
new PointF(347.5F, 247.5F),
new PointF(442.5F, 97.5F),
new PointF(402.5F, 17.5F),
new PointF(137.5F, 7.5F),
new PointF(312.5F, 167.5F),
new PointF(297.5F, 322.5F),
new PointF(397.5F, 172.5F),
new PointF(437.5F, 247.5F),
new PointF(387.5F, 322.5F),
new PointF(352.5F, 87.5F),
new PointF(312.5F, 7.5F),
new PointF(272.5F, 82.5F),
new PointF(222.5F, 7.5F),
new PointF(77.5F, 372.5F),
new PointF(477.5F, 322.5F) };

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want the [*root mean square* distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65640/how-to-calculate-2d-standard-deviation-with-0-mean-bounded-by-limits) around the centers of the circles. [This answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/172926/root-mean-square-error-rms-error/) from the OpenCV QA forum has a simple solution:

> Use both `x` and `y` coordinates , loop over your points and use this formula :
>
> `MEAN_X += pow(x - x0, 2);`
>      `MEAN_Y += pow(y - y0, 2);`
>      `TOTAL_RMS =  sqrt( 1/n * (MEAN_X + MEAN_Y));`
>
> `x , y` : coordinates from image2
>   `x0 , y0`: coordinates from image1
>   `n` : number of points

Comment: I appreciate the answer. My follow-up question is how to apply this to each image to determine whether or not the circle is likely a circle at all? Is the RMS the number I need to check other circles against or is it applied more like a standard deviation? Thanks in advance for your forgiveness of my ignorance here.

Comment: This method would require that you've already matched each circle to it's closest point in the last frame (I thought this was the case from reading your post originally but now not sure; was just going off the general "how to apply std dev to 2D"). If you had say a single circle, then the `x` and `y` coordinates looped over would be from the previous `N` frames. If you did this same thing for multiple circles, you'd have an RMS for each circle from the previous `N` frames. Then you can reject a circle in a particular frame when it has a notably different RMS than the other circles.